# PowerShell 3.0 -iin operator support of wildcards? How to use -ilike in a similar way?

Tags: arrays, powershell, wildcard, operator-keyword, regexp-like

I put together some PowerShell code to search for PDFs where the name matches any of the filenames (in an array of values named $overlayTargetFilenames containing Name.pdf Name2.pdf Name3.pdf) but with an exact match:

```
$matchedDrawings = Get-ChildItem $basePath -Directory -Force -Exclude 'Undesired 1','Undesired 2' | Get-ChildItem -Directory -Force | Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -Include '*.pdf' | where {$_.FullName -like '* A Target Subfolder\*' -and $_.FullName -notmatch "\\OLD" -and $_.Name -iin $overlayTargetFilenames} | sort($_.basename) | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to do a similar search for PDFs where the array of values has wildcards, such as how to make -iin (which is case insensitive "IN" operator, reverse argument order of -icontains) work like -ilike does for wildcards.

How must I modify the code above to work if the $overlayTargetFilenames had values like Name_* Name-2_* More-Name3_* -- looking for any basenames starting with those different searches? The sought names are generated earlier by the code, and the list size varies wildly.

I've tried -iin and -ilike.

Comment: convert your list of target partial names into a regex OR. `@('One_*', 'Two_*', 'Three_*')` would become `'One_|Two_|Three_'`. then use that in a `$Collection -match $RegexOrPattern`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'm hesitant to go to RegEx on this one, only because if the filename strings sought have characters that RegEx tries to interpret, then it could mess things up. Does PowerShell have a function to automagically escape such content for RegEx?

Comment: `[regex]::Escape(string)` is the .NET regex escape method.

Comment: @TravisBennett - the reply by `AdminOfThings` covers that. [*grin*]

Comment: Ok, it worked, now make it an answer so I can award points!
 | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "\.[^\.]+$"} | ForEach-Object {'^'+[regex]::Escape($_)+'_.*'}
# Format to basename (no extension) and add ^ prefix and _ suffix then .* regexp post suffix.

$SpecialTargetFilenamesRegExp = "$($SpecialTargetFilenames -join "|")"
#Join array into RegEx | Seperated OR string

$matchedSpecials = $matchedSpecials | where {$_.Name -match $SpecialTargetFilenamesRegExp}
#Do the jingle! Do the jingle!

Comment: Can I award an answer directly to a comment, like the one by @Lee_Dailey and/or AdminOfThings ?

Comment: @TravisBennett - nope ... but you can ask that person [or persons] to post the comment as an answer. [*grin*] i was 1st, but AdminOfThings gave the specific answer - so i would ask him to post the official answer & give the award to him.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Please copy your response, or from my long comment, so I can assign an answer.

Comment: @TravisBennett, I posted an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regex match on values piped into a `Foreach-Object`. For values that may have special regex characters, you can use the `Escape()` method from the .NET Regex class. The result will be a string with all the escape characters needed for regex.

```
$Collection | Foreach-Object {
    $regex = [Regex]::Escape($_)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the `-in` operator does not support wildcards; it basically enumerates and checks similar to `-eq`.  If you want wildcards, you need to iterate yourself and use `-like`.